# Indesign: Error message when adding moving or deleting pages

Tags: adobe-indesign

Indesign won't let me add, delete or move a page:

Error message:

> Requested operation would cause one or more objects to be too small. Please check whether the stroke weight is too large.

Comment: And so, did you check the stroke weight. What's its value ?